# What is the perimeters of this Arduino sleep setAlarm function?

Tags: c++, arduino

`RTC.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_HOURS, 33, 18, 0);   //set your wake-up time here`

Is it 33 seconds, 18 minutes, zero hours?

The readme file references an Adafruit library it's made from. From there, I can't find where it actually says the parameters of `setAlarm`.

- [adafruit.github.io/RTClib](http://adafruit.github.io/RTClib)

  - [adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_r_t_c___d_s3231.html](https://adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_r_t_c___d_s3231.html)
- [github.com/adafruit/RTClib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib)

The libraries (in the sketch) are as follows:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClibExtended.h>
#include <LowPower.h>
```

Comment: "The libraries (in the script)" - It's *not* a script. C++ is a compiled language, *not* a scripting language.

Comment: I meant sketch. Changed.

Comment: You meant "source code" I believe.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's also from another library. I just searched the code itself, and found this: https://github.com/JChristensen/DS3232RTC#alarm-methods

```
  RTC.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_SECONDS, 30, 00, 0, 0);   //set your wake-up time here:
  RTC.setAlarm(ALM2_MATCH_MINUTES, 0, 10, 0, 0);  //where "xx" is minutes
  // every 00 minutes past the hour;
  // if every minute is needed change MINUTES to SECONDS (only for ALM1)
  // matches seconds AND minutes when _MINUTES is used. Sequence of time:
  // first seconds, then minutes, hours, daydate
  // or: seconds (but enter 00, is ignored), minutes then hours, daydate for ALM2
  // zero's mean: always
  // example: Set alarm1 every day at 18:33
  // RTC.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_HOURS, 33, 18, 0);  set your wake-up time here
  // RTC.alarmInterrupt(1, true);
```

Therefore, the alarm is set every day at 18:33.

`RTC.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_HOURS, [minute], [hour], 0);`